# Absolute positioned div, prevent background scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a Bootstrap popover for a dynamic list that can be several pages long. I simply added a overflow: scroll to it and it works, however if the page is longer than the list, it continues scrolling past the popover.

Is it possible to disable scrolling of the background content while the popover is open?

In other words can you have an absolute positioned div scroll while disabling scrolling of the background content?

**UPDATE: Fixed the issue based on both answers**

```
$('#message-preview-trigger').on('show.bs.popover', function () {
    $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
});

$('#message-preview-trigger').on('hide.bs.popover', function () {
    $('body').css('overflow', 'visible');       
})
```

Comment: show your code please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set both `overflow: hidden;` to body element and `overflow: auto;` to the modal dialog when the modal is open.

To be more clear we'd need to see your code.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a pretty simple example ;

[Scroll](https://jsfiddle.net/6eyJm/1/)

Your popup should be in another div:

```
<div id="shadow">
<div id="popup">
    <a id='close' href="#">Close</a>
</div>
```

Then trying adding these CSS codes on the root div:

```
#shadow{
display: none;
position: fixed;
top:0;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
height:100%;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
```

**Then there's the little JS trick : **

```
  $('#open').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault()
   $('body').width($('body').width());
   $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
   $('#shadow').css('display', 'block');
  })
   $('#close').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault()
   $('body, #shadow').removeAttr('style')
})
```

Hope it Helps..... :)